# How to add two transaction function in a script file?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner in hyperledger. My `model.cto` file has two transaction processor function one for transferring the car from manufacturer to the showroom and another one is for transferring the car from showroom to owner. `model.cto` file is given below,

```
namespace org.manufacturer.network

asset Car identified by carID {
  o String carID
  o String name
  o String chasisNumber
  --> Showroom showroom
  --> Owner owner
}

participant Showroom identified by showroomID {
  o String showroomID
  o String name
}

participant Owner identified by ownerID {
  o String ownerID
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

transaction Allocate {
  --> Car  car
  --> Showroom newShowroom
}

transaction Purchase {
  --> Showroom showroom
  --> Owner newOwner
}
```

So, I want to add two functions in my `script.js` file, so that I could perform my transactions. My `script.js` file is given below

```
/**
 * New script file
 * @param {org.manufacturer.network.Allocate} allocate - allocating the car from manufacturer to showroom
 * @param {org.manufacturer.network.Purchase} purchase - purchase the car by owner from showroom
 * @transaction
 */

async function transferCar(allocate){
  allocate.car.showroom = allocate.newShowroom;
  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.manufacturer.network.Car');
  await assetRegistry.update(allocate.car);
}

async function purchaseCar(purchase){
  purchase.car.owner = purchase.newOwner;
  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.manufacturer.network.Car');
  await assetRegistry.update(purchase.car);
}
```

But the script file is giving error as `Transaction processing function transferCar must have 1 function argument of type transaction.`

How to add multiple transaction processor functions in a single `script.js` file? 
Is that possible or I have to create two `script.js` file to handle the transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the correct way to define two transactions in the script.js file.

Your script.js file should be like this:

```
/**
 * New script file
 * @param {org.manufacturer.network.Allocate} allocate - allocating the car from manufacturer to showroom
 * @transaction
 */

async function transferCar(allocate){
  allocate.car.showroom = allocate.newShowroom;
  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.manufacturer.network.Car');
  await assetRegistry.update(allocate.car);
}

/**
 * New script file
 * @param {org.manufacturer.network.Purchase} purchase - purchase the car by owner from showroom
 * @transaction
 */

async function purchaseCar(purchase){
  purchase.car.owner = purchase.newOwner;
  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.manufacturer.network.Car');
  await assetRegistry.update(purchase.car);
}
```

This is how you can add more than one transaction in the script.js file.

I hope it will help you.